# how to watch std::wstring var in Visual Studio 6.0 debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, watch, wstring

I got

```
std::string str = "hello world";
std::wstring wstr = L"goodbye world";
std::cout << str << std::endl;
std::wcout << wstr << std::endl;
```

and when I start debug and set breakpoint at third line
 in debugger "Auto" window in VS 6.0 I got:

```
std::cout   {...}
str {0x001f2de1 "hello world"}
wstr    {0x001f2e4a}
```

and I can't see wstr value...

How I could configure VS to be able to this??

thanx

Comment: Upgrade. Your compiler is notoriously horrifically terrible.

Comment: +1 on upgrading the compiler, VC6 is one of the worst un-comformant C++ compilers on the market.  You might get away with upgrading VC6 to the latest Service Pack, think it's SP6.  If you can migrate off it, then certainly do so.

Comment: SP6 is already on board, and it's not possible to upgrade.
thanx anyway

Comment: Why do people still want to work with compilers being obsolete for 14 years now?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Usually because the code is that old, and the Powers That Be have decided either that rewriting it in a modern language is too risky, or that exposing their minions to modern C++ might make them more of a flight risk.

Comment: because they make money at it

Answer (score 5):

This quote is from VisualStudio 6.0 autoexp.dat:

> -------   Unicode  -------
>
> If your application is built for Unicode, you'll want Unicode
>   strings to automatically expand as text, rather than arrays of
>   unsigned short.  To automatically display Unicode strings as   text,
>   go to Tools/Options/Debug tab and check 'Display Unicode  strings'.

So in your VisualStudio 6.0 you should go to **Tools/Options/Debug** and **turn on "Display Unicode strings"**.

After that you will see:

> - std::cout   {...}
> - str {0x00441d21 "hello world"}
> - wstr    {0x00441cb2 "goodbye world"}

Answer (score 0):

add a watch on:

str._Bx._Ptr

if the string is less than 16 chars then we should watch

str._Bx._Buf

Comment: there isn't any _Bx member in string class, as I see

Comment: VC6 has a very old `std::` implementation. The `_Bx._Buf` looks like it comes from VC7.